# Rvest returns empty table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the table on this website: http://fluxnet.fluxdata.org/sites/site-list-and-pages/?view=table, using the following code:

```
library(rvest) url <- "http://fluxnet.fluxdata.org/sites/site-list-and-pages/?view=table"

tbl <- url %>%
       read_html() %>%
       html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="siteTable"]') %>%
       html_table()
```

However the returned table has the header only, but no data at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: You will probably have to load the page using some tool, e.g. phantomjs.

Comment: actually, if I open the link, I see only the header of the table and no data, so there may be something about the website

Comment: @giocomai that's weird, because I just tried opening the URL in three different browsers (under anonymous mode to make sure no cookies were loaded), and it opens fine.

Comment: oh, now it works. So if it is just this page, once it has loaded, you can save locally the html file from the browser. then you run your commands, but instead of the URL, point at location of the file on your hard drive. It should work.

Comment: @giocomai, that was a very good idea and it worked! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just for individual pages, the easiest solution is to open the page in a browser, and save it as an html file on your local hard drive.

Then you can run the above lines of code pointing at the location of the file on your hard drive instead of the remote URL. It should work.